# How to create 3D line effect over images

Tags: 3d, effects, jquery-effects

I'm new to stackoverflow, but its a website I frequently come to when I need some coding help.

I'm wondering if anyone can pinpoint what exactly this effect over the image on this template is (not the word offset, but the 3D line effect overtop the image that moves with the cursor) on this website preview: http://preview.themeforest.net/item/aqura-music-band-musicians-djs-html-template/full_screen_preview/14138040

I'm having trouble researching it, because I'm not sure what it would be called. If anyone has an idea, I don't necessarily require the how-to, but I would appreciate any lead.

I'd like to recreate my own version of it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Particle.js](http://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/) for this.